# Creating Textboxes dynamically in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create multiple rows of text boxes using a button. Every time the button is pressed a new row with four text boxes appears. I tried to use a function to do this and store the number of rows in a variable, but I am not able to update the variable after the row gets created. Also after requisite rows are created, I have to fetch the data from the text boxes.  How do I get this done?

Answer (score 2):

The example below produces a GUI that produces 4 entries each time the button is pressed:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def add_four_entries():
    global root, my_list_of_entries
    for _ in range(4):
        my_list_of_entries.append(tk.Entry(root))
        my_list_of_entries[-1].pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_list_of_entries = list()
    tk.Button(root, text="Add 4 more", command=add_four_entries).pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Although your answer doesn't address the problem stated in the question exactly, but it gave me an idea about how to solve the problem. I used multidimensional array to store the boxes. Thanks @Nae

Comment: @Ubi How does it not address the question exactly?

Comment: I need text boxes in two dimensions in the form of a spreadsheet, your code creates a single column of text boxes. and I also need to fetch all the values from that two dimensional grid of text boxes.